# Getting atayahmet/laravel-nestable to work with form model binding

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, laravel-5

**Situation:**

I need nested dropdown list.

**What I have used?**

[atayahmet/laravel-nestable](https://github.com/atayahmet/laravel-nestable)

**Problem**

I have used `Category::selected(1)->renderAsDropdown();` as mentioned in documentation but I'm only able to get the drop down, **I need necessary item to be selected.** I don't think form model binding works in this situation.

I'm using Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it(kind of)!
instruction was missing in documentation.. 
had to do 
**Category::selected('selected'=>'1')->renderAsDropdown();**
but still shows in multiple selection instead of a drop down! so i had to comment some lines out